# how do I check if all characters in a string is space or alphabet? C++

Tags: c++

I need to make a program which converts all letters to uppercase.

But first I need to get an input from the user. And I need to check if there are characters that are not space or alphabet.

This is what I tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s;
cout << "Enter a string: ";

while (getline(cin, s)){
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if ((isspace(s[i]) || isalpha(s[i]))){
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
            }
            cout << s << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cout << "Invalid string. Please input only alphabets or space character. " << endl << "Enter a string: ";
    }
}

//if the input value is valid convert and print

return 0;}
```

This program successfully make error messages to pure numbers and pure question marks. But the problem is if there are invalid characters and valid characters mixed in the input, it cannot distinguish it.

For example, if input is "Hi?", the program thinks its a valid input. But with questions marks, the string should be invalid.

I think the for statement is the problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: _`return 1;`_ sure you didn't want `continue;` instead?

Comment: with continue; I get wrong output..

Comment: Well `return` just exits your program, is that what you want at that point?

Comment: Yes. If the string contains only alphabets and spaces, I want convert them into uppercase and print. After that I want to end the program.

Comment: But the problem is the program can not recognize "Hi?" as an invalid input. I think the for statement is the problem. Hi? shouldn't be converted into uppercase because it has a question mark in it(which is not an alphabet nor space.).

Comment: But it will stop the loops completely at the 1st match.  It doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: If numbers are typed in, the program repeatedly gets input from the user. Isn't that not a problem if it gets inputs again?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes to deal with the break out conditions in your loops without changing the structure of your program too much.

Here's one example how you could get it to work. Comments in the code.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;

    while(std::cout << "Enter a string: " && std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        bool valid = true;  // will stay true unless at least one char is invalid
        for(char& ch : s) { // use a range-based for loop
                            // ch is now a reference to the char in the string

            // convert to unsigned char - these functions are not safe
            // otherwise:

            if(std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)) ||
               std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))) 
            {
                ch = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
                continue; // continue to check the next character
            }
            std::cout << "Invalid character ('" << ch << "') in string.\n"
                         "Please input only alphabets or space character.\n";
            valid = false; // to let the user enter a new string
            break; // no need to check more characters, the string is invalid
        }
        if(valid) break; // break out only if all characters are valid
    }
    if(std::cin)
        std::cout << "The valid string is now " << s << '\n';
}
```

A similar program could use algorithms from `<algorithm>` to do the check and the transformation of the string to uppercase.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;

    // the manual loop replaced by a simple algorithm that checks if any
    // character in the string is invalid by using a lambda, here called
    // "is_invalid":

    auto is_invalid = [](unsigned char ch) {
        return !(std::isspace(ch) || std::isalpha(ch));
    };

    while(std::cout << "Enter a string: " &&
          std::getline(std::cin, s) &&
          std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), is_invalid))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid character in string.\n"
                     "Please input only alphabets or space character.\n";
    }

    if(std::cin) {
        // transform the valid string to uppercase using another lambda.
        // the lambda is here only to make the chars into unsigned chars
        // to make the use of std::toupper safe

        auto to_upper = [](unsigned char ch) { return std::toupper(ch); };
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), to_upper);

        std::cout << "The valid string is now " << s << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a manual loop to check each `char`, consider using [`std::all_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), eg: `bool valid = std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char ch){ return std::isspace(ch) || std::isalpha(ch); }); if (valid) { std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](unsigned char ch){ return std::toupper(ch); }); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree. Added something like that as an option.